# Generate unique id in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I create a table with custom `ID` like `22/00/00001` with a sequence? Sorry I'm a newbie with databases. All help will be appreciated thank you!

I am an intern at a hospital. I have to rewrite a database with SQL Server, I have a problem with specific ID numbers. It must be in `year/month/id00001` format, for example `11/22/02586`. And each department must have its own patient counter. Any help will be appreciated thanks!.

Example:

[image]

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MySequence
AS INT
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1;
GO

-- Create a new table called 'PATIENT' in schema 'dbo'
-- Drop the table if it already exists

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.PATIENT', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.PATIENT
GO

-- Create the table in the specified schema
CREATE TABLE dbo.PATIENT
(
    NUM_PAT [VARCHAR] (20) NOT NULL 
        PRIMARY KEY 
        CONSTRAINT [DF_PATIENT_ID_PATIENT]
            DEFAULT FORMAT ((NEXT VALUE FOR MySequence), '22/00/00000#'), -- primary key column
    NOM_PAT [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    PREN_PAT [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    DN_PAT [DATE] NOT NULL,
    -- specify more columns here
);
GO

-- Insert rows into table 'PATIENT'
INSERT INTO PATIENT ([NOM_PAT], [PREN_PAT], [DN_PAT])
VALUES ('fred', 'alves', '25/11/1990'),
       ('alvaldo', 'merlin', '11/09/1985');
-- add more rows here
GO
```

[image]

Comment: Aside... can we stop using 2 digit years already? Y2k was a thing. Your original data uses 4 digit years so don't break it by creating identifiers containing years but with only 2 digits.

Comment: Quick question - what do you mean by 'And each department must have its own patient counter.'? Does this mean duplicate IDs e.g., ID `22/00/00001` refers to Bob Smith in one department, but in another department `22/00/00001` is for Sally Lee?

Answer (score 0):

I'm checking your request, I think you can aproach in two way, a  way is define a table where you will save the patient id  and a column with  counter to generate your custom id
Example

Table name like PatientCounter

```
PatientID, PatientCounter
1                 1
2                 125
```

Or in table patient add a column Counter, I prefer the thing separeted, but this also is a option, then in the query you could do something like that.

```
DECLARE @PatientId as int
DECLARE @PatientCount as int

SET @PatientId = 21
SET @PatientCount = 1

SELECT   
    CAST(FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yy') as nvarchar(4)) + '/' +  
    CAST(MONTH(getDATE()) as nvarchar(4)) + '/' + 
    CAST(@PatientId as nvarchar(10)) +  
    CAST(REPLICATE('0', 5 - LEN(@PatientCount + 1)) + RTrim(@PatientCount + 1) as nvarchar(50)) as MyCustomId
```

The result

```
MyCustomId
22/11/2100002
```

And after confirming that your application has consumed this custom id, update the counter in the table.

```
UPDATE PatientTable SET PatientCount = PatientCount + 1 WHERE PatientID = @PatientId
```

Best Regards